# Read a SQL query from java

Tags: java, mysql, text

I want this query to be read from java --->

```
 select Fname, Lname, Mark 
 from Student, grade
 where Student.SSN = Grade.SSN 
   and (Fname = "Nikos" OR Lname = "Nikolaou")
```

I have written this code...

```
// Reading query file...
ArrayList<String> queryFile = ReadFile(queryFileName);
String[] selectArgs = queryFile.get(0).trim().split(",");
String[] fromArgs = queryFile.get(1).trim().split(",");
String[] andConditions = queryFile.get(2).trim().split("AND");
List<String> orConditions = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but I can think any way how to train my code for line which we have "where"  to read first "() ", then AND, or conditions ...and finally <,>,=

I want the program to be dynamic ... the user give any query in .txt file and the java program read it from there .... any ideas?

Comment: You may need a language parser: http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: hmm..can you explain the requirements? what happens to different arrays after that? Just curious..

Comment: you are trying to write a SQL parser.  However, the SQL standard is extremely complex and it seems too big assignment.  have you looked at any 3rd party lib? try "java sql parser" at google

Comment: for example: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser

Comment: the requirements are just ---> 5. Write a Java program that gets as input (in the command line) the name of a query's specification file and prints out the results, separated by ","

i want to connect java with redis ....so i put the data into redis with gson ... .... but my only problem in the hole this assig nment is to read this difficult "where line " and get right results...

Comment: I think he/she was asking **what** do you do with the arrays (this question looks like a [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/))